# Process a list of 1,000+ URLs with cURL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I took on a freelance job to create a PHP script using cURL that will take a list of URLs, each URL redirects to a new URL so the goal is to input a list of URL's and the result is to get a list back of the URL's that they all redirect to.

I was able to accomplish this with `curl_multi_exec` my script currently runs 5 curl handles in parallel and on the 5 one it starts a new batch for the next 5.  I have increased PHP's timeout and memory and it works really well on a list of like 100 URLs.

The problem is the guy wants to be able to input 1,000 or more URLs and run it.  When I do this with his list it will run for about 7-8 minutes and eventually it will just go white screen on me.

When I started the project I was told 100 URLs so that is why I went this route but with such a large list I am thinking I should use a MySQL database to import all the URLs and then cycle though them at like 100 at a time.

I am just looking for some feedback if anyone knows a better method or if there is a way to do this without using a database?  Any ideas please?

Comment: Yes, this should get queued into a database and run by a backend script periodically.

Comment: Can you do this on the command line with PHP? That way you don't have time constraints.

Comment: A database would certainly work, but it's trivial enough that input and output textfiles would do the trick.

Comment: @halfer that is something I will have to try

Comment: (Or of course you can turn off your time constraints in your Apache env, but it's not recommended.)

Comment: This is probably not suitable for real-time reporting, unless you use something like AJAX to fetch the new rows as they're available, or check to see if the results are finished, and update the results on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you, that "the guy" import the list into a database and you can retrieve the URLs from there, writing back the results to the DB.

However,... you could start your PHP script as CLI script (using command line), then you might not have a timeout problem. But this implies, that the list of URLs will be available via CLI, e.g. as a textfile on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy that your script works, albeit slowly, then consider just adding a flush after each batch of 5. That way the browser might not timeout while waiting. Alternatively write the output to a separate file (still using flush) and use ajax to query the file until done.